# append ul li element to react DOM

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

hi i have the code written in java-script and that is working fine, now for some of reason i need to convert that in react, i had searched about this in google but unfortunately didn't found any helpful things, here below is my code written in javascript

```
let message_pane = $(".msg_card_body");
let currentTime = formatAMPM(new Date());
 message_pane.append(
        "<div class='d-flex justify-content-start'>" +
        "<div class='msg_cotainer'>" +
        "<div class='msg_time'>You "+"<span>"+ currentTime +"</span>"+"</div>" +
        "<div>"+text+"</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>");
```

**Tried methods**

Setting state:-

```
state = {
remoteStreams: [],
Message:'',
incomemsgs:[],
};
```

appending msg to state

```
let me = this;
  // console.warn(text + 'received');
  me.setState(
  {
    incomemsgs: {
      text
    }
  })
```

rendering:-

```
   {Object.keys(this.state.incomemsgs).map(key => {
              let msgs = this.state.incomemsgs[key];
              return (
                <div
                  key={msgs}
                />
              );
            })}
```

but the above tried thing didn't worked, this may be dumb question but really i stuck here from long time,  any helps or suggestions are heartly thank you.

Comment: `didn't worked` what happened.

Comment: hi @James it's showing nothing on screen and no errors too.

Answer (score 0):

if you are starting to use react, I would recommend you to go over its docs (specially this one https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

regarding to your problem. state.incomemsgs seems to be an array, but when updating your state you change it to an object instead of creating a new array and adding your new entry.

```
class MessageFeed extends React.Component {
 state = {
   incomemsgs:[]
 }

 onIncommingMessage(message) {
  this.setState(prev => {
    return {
      ...prev,
      incomemsgs: [...prev.incomemsgs, message]
    }
  });
 }

 render() {
  return (
    <div>
     {this.state.incomemsgs.map(entry => (
      <div key={entry.id}>{entry.text}</div>
     ))}
    </div>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: hi @angelSalazar, thank you very much for your time, but getting error of entry of undefined at ` this.state.incomemsgs.map(entry => (
      <div key={entry.id}>{entry.text}</div>
     ))`

Comment: what I provided is an example, when mapping over your incomemsgs, you have to replace id and text for the right properties (which I do not know). id must be a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Your append function adds the same group of elements every message. In that case this part

```
"<div class='d-flex justify-content-start'>" +
    "<div class='msg_cotainer'>" +
    "<div class='msg_time'>You "+"<span>"+ currentTime +"</span>"+"</div>" +
    "<div>"+text+"</div>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>"
```

Can be converted into a React component.

```
import React from "react";

const MessageDisplay = props => {
  return (
    <div className="d-flex justify-content-start">
      <div className="msg_cotainer">
        <div className="msg_time">
          You <span>{props.receiveTime}</span>
        </div>
        <div>{props.text}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MessageDisplay;
```

Now this component can be rendered from an array of Message objects. I have created a codesandbox which simulates this

[See here](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-star-kdgy8?file=/src/App.js)

I set up some predefined messages in "messageBank" constant, which gets "recieved" on a 1 second interval within the useEffect to simulate recieving messages and updating the page through the map method.